# Loop through element id's

Tags: jquery, loops, remove-if

I have this jQuery code to detect if all the values in a column are empty, and, if they are, remove the column:

```
var valid=0;
jQuery("#column1 input[type=text]").each(function(){
    if(jQuery(this).val() != "") valid+=1;
});

if(valid ==0){
    jQuery("td#column1").hide();
}

var valid1=0;
jQuery("#column2 input[type=text]").each(function(){
    if(jQuery(this).val() != "") valid1+=1;
});

if(valid1 ==0){
    jQuery("td#column2").hide();
}
```

Is there any way of turning this in to a loop so, that it goes through each column `(#column1, #column2, etc..)` and removes that column if needed, s I don't have to duplicate the above code for each column?

Thanks in advance for any help.

**EDIT**

Thanks for all the suggestions.
The issue with some of the answers is that the loop would remove individual cells. I need the loop to work out if all of the fields under the header are empty if they are remove the whole column including the header.

```
<table>
<tr id="prod_specs_header">
<td><span class="tooltips-link" title="">Product Code</span></td>
<td id="column1"><span class="tooltips-link isimg" title=""><img style="opacity: 1; visibility: visible;" src="templates/autcastorsandwheels/images/icon_wheel_diam.gif" data-src="templates/autcastorsandwheels/images/icon_wheel_diam.gif" border="0"></span></td>
<td id="column2"><span class="tooltips-link isimg" title=""><img style="opacity: 1; visibility: visible;" src="templates/autcastorsandwheels/images/icon_wheel_width.gif" data-src="templates/autcastorsandwheels/images/icon_wheel_width.gif" border="0"></span></td>
<td id="column3"><span class="tooltips-link isimg" title=""><img style="opacity: 1; visibility: visible;" src="templates/autcastorsandwheels/images/icon_overall_height.gif" data-src="templates/autcastorsandwheels/images/icon_overall_height.gif" border="0"></span></td>
<td id="column4"><span class="tooltips-link isimg" title=""><img style="opacity: 1; visibility: visible;" src="templates/autcastorsandwheels/images/icon_plate_dimen.gif" data-src="templates/autcastorsandwheels/images/icon_plate_dimen.gif" border="0"></span></td>
<td id="column5"><span class="tooltips-link isimg" title=""><img style="opacity: 1; visibility: visible;" src="templates/autcastorsandwheels/images/icon_hole_spacing.gif" data-src="templates/autcastorsandwheels/images/icon_hole_spacing.gif" border="0"></span></td>
<td id="column6"><span class="tooltips-link isimg" title=""><img style="opacity: 1; visibility: visible;" src="templates/autcastorsandwheels/images/icon_hole_width.gif" data-src="templates/autcastorsandwheels/images/icon_hole_width.gif" border="0"></span></td>
<td id="column7"><span class="tooltips-link isimg" title=""><img style="opacity: 1; visibility: visible;" src="templates/autcastorsandwheels/images/icon_offset.gif" data-src="templates/autcastorsandwheels/images/icon_offset.gif" border="0"></span></td>
<td id="column8"><span class="tooltips-link isimg" title=""><img style="opacity: 1; visibility: visible;" src="templates/autcastorsandwheels/images/icon_carrycap.gif" data-src="templates/autcastorsandwheels/images/icon_carrycap.gif" border="0"></span></td>
<td id="column9"><span class="tooltips-link isimg" title=""><img style="opacity: 1; visibility: visible;" src="templates/autcastorsandwheels/images/icon_unit_weight.gif" data-src="templates/autcastorsandwheels/images/icon_unit_weight.gif" border="0"></span></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>37TAS5700</td>
<td class="field" id="column1"><input value="50" type="text"></td>
<td class="field" id="column2"><input value="" type="text"></td>
<td class="field" id="column3"><input value="71" type="text"></td>
<td class="field" id="column4"><input value="" type="text"></td>
<td class="field" id="column5"><input value="46/38x46/38" type="text"></td>
<td class="field" id="column6"><input value="" type="text"></td>
<td class="field" id="column7"><input value="" type="text"></td>
<td class="field" id="column8"><input value="40" type="text"></td>
<td class="field" id="column9"><input value="0.14" type="text"></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>37TAS5701</td>
<td class="field" id="column1"><input value="75" type="text"></td>
<td class="field" id="column2"><input value="" type="text"></td>
<td class="field" id="column3"><input value="100" type="text"></td>
<td class="field" id="column4"><input value="" type="text"></td>
<td class="field" id="column5"><input value="46/38x46/38" type="text"></td>
<td class="field" id="column6"><input value="" type="text"></td>
<td class="field" id="column7"><input value="" type="text"></td>
<td class="field" id="column8"><input value="50" type="text"></td>
<td class="field" id="column9"><input value="0.34" type="text"></td>
</tr>

<tr><td>37TAS5702</td>
<td class="field" id="column1"><input value="100" type="text"></td>
<td class="field" id="column2"><input value="" type="text"></td>
<td class="field" id="column3"><input value="122" type="text"></td>
<td class="field" id="column4"><input value="" type="text"></td>
<td class="field" id="column5"><input value="46/38x46/38" type="text"></td>
<td class="field" id="column6"><input value="" type="text"></td>
<td class="field" id="column7"><input value="" type="text"></td>
<td class="field" id="column8"><input value="65" type="text"></td>
<td class="field" id="column9"><input value="0.55" type="text"></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: What does the HTML look like?

Comment: As IDs must be unique on context page, your code seems strange to me, can you post relevant HTML code?

Comment: You should give each column a class, not an id, and then follow @virus721's suggestion.

Comment: So OP, will you consider to provide relevant HTML code or not???

Comment: sorry for the delay on the html but is this what you required?

Answer (score 0):

You can first loop the column and then inner elements

```
jQuery("[id^=column]").each(function(){
   valid = 0;
   jQuery(this).find("input[type=text]").each(function(){
      if(jQuery(this).val() != "") valid+=1;
   });

  if(valid ==0){
    jQuery(this).hide();
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var valid = new array();
$('[id^="column"]').each(function() {
    if ($(this).find('input:text').val().length !== 0) {
        valid[$(this).index()] = 1;
    } else {
        valid[$(this).index()] = 0;
        $(this).hide();
    }
});
```

You'll need to create an array of `valid` and then you can step through the columns, setting a valid indicator for each while hiding the empties.

Answer (score 0):

Give all the TDs the class `column`, then:

```
$("td.column").each(function() {
    var valid = false;
    $(this).find("input[type=text]").each(function() {
        if(jQuery(this).val() != "") {
            valid = true;
            return false; // end the .each immediately
        }
    });
    if (!valid) {
        $(this).hide();
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your help - I tried this suggestion which almost worked apart from it doesnt detect whether all of the fields in the column are empty and then remove the full column including its header - it seems to remove all td's with no content? all the headers disappear? if one of the fields in the column has a value then I want the full column to stay.

Comment: I wrote it before you posted your HTML. The HTML doesn't match what I imagined it to be based on your code. Since IDs are required to be unique, I thought each `#columnN` would be a single `TD` with a bunch of `INPUT`s in it.

Answer (score 0):

Since it's short answer day:

```
$('[id^="column"]:not(:has(input:text:not([value=""])))').hide();
```